# request.setAttribute inside a loop

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a servlet in my j2EE project, where i'm calculating some materials for a hardwood project. I have an ArrayList where i'm adding the necessary amount of materials needed. I want to set the ArrayList as a reqeust attribute so i eventually can display them on a jsp page.

```
  String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws LoginSampleException {

  //here is going to a mehtod to acces to database and get the information

    ArrayList<Tree> trees = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Tree tree: trees){
         int amount = tree.calculate(tree.getLength(), tree.getLengthPrUnit());
         ArrayList <Integer> amountMaterials = new ArrayList<>();
         amountMaterials.add(amount);
         request.setAttribute("amountMaterials", amountMaterials);
    }

return null; // here I'm eventually going to redirect to my jsp-page
}
```

Should i put the request.setAttribute outside of the loop or does it not matter

here is the alternative version

```
  ArrayList<Integer> amountMaterials = null; 

    ArrayList<Tree> trees = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Tree tree: trees){
         int amount = tree.calculate(tree.getLength(), tree.getLengthPrUnit());
         amountMaterials.add(amount);

    }
    request.setAttribute("amountMaterials", amountMaterials);

return null; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below explanation:

**First Version:**

```
ArrayList<Tree> trees = new ArrayList<>();
for(Tree tree: trees) {
     int amount = tree.calculate(tree.getLength(), tree.getLengthPrUnit());
     ArrayList <Integer> amountMaterials = new ArrayList<>();
     amountMaterials.add(amount);
     request.setAttribute("amountMaterials", amountMaterials);
}
```

1. In this code version you are trying to create new `ArrayList` every time, if you have more `Tree` objects that many ArrayList objects will be created.
2. `request.setAttribute()` if you put this code inside loop with same attribute name `amountMaterials` previous values will overridden with the new values, and finally you will have only one value and that is the last calculated value.

So first version not suggested.

**Second Version:**

```
ArrayList<Integer> amountMaterials = null; 

ArrayList<Tree> trees = new ArrayList<>();
for(Tree tree: trees){
     int amount = tree.calculate(tree.getLength(), tree.getLengthPrUnit());
     amountMaterials.add(amount);

}
request.setAttribute("amountMaterials", amountMaterials);
```

In this you are created ArrayList object outside of the loop so it will created only one instance and it will have all the values and `request.setAttribute()` is outside of the loop which means your previous values will not be overridden.

By this explanation now you know which version to use ;).